# Ruby: calculate the frequencies of the string text letters

Tags: ruby, frequency

I was creating a ruby programme that will calculate the frequency of each letter appearing in my text and will be return it as a Hash.

Below is my code:

```
class LetterHistogram
  attr_reader :letters
  attr_accessor :text

  def initialize(t = "Hello World!")
    @text = t
  end

  def display
    calculateFrequencies
    ("A".."Z").each {|x| puts "#{x}: " + "*" * letters[x]}
  end

  private
  attr_writer :letters

  def calculateFrequencies
    calcuFreq = String.new(text)
    calcuFreq.upcase!.gsub!(/\W+/, '')
    letters.clear
    letters.default = 0
    calcuFreq.each_char {|char| letters[char] += 1}
  end
end
```

But I getting this error when I run the display method
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZzE2.png)

What is the error means and how to solve it?

Comment: Please include your error message as part of the question in text, not as an image...if that image gets taken down or otherwise goes away, this question becomes unanswerable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that in `calculateFrequencies` you are using a not assigned variable: `letters`. So, when you call `calculateFrequencies` in `display`, `letters = nil` and calling `.clear` on `nil` returns the error.

This is a modified version of the code, using snake_case (which is the Ruby writing standard).

```
class LetterHistogram
  attr_accessor :text

  def initialize(t = "Hello World!")
    @text = t
  end

  def display
    calculate_frequencies.each { |letter, freq| puts "#{letter}: #{freq}"}
  end

  private

  def calculate_frequencies
    freq = @text.upcase.gsub!(/\W+/, '').each_char.with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |letter, freq| freq[letter] += 1 }
    freq.sort_by{ |letter, freq| freq }.reverse # just to sort
  end
end
```

Instantiating an object and calling `.display` on it:

```
senctence = LetterHistogram.new
senctence.display

#=> L: 3 
#=> O: 2 
#=> D: 1 
#=> R: 1 
#=> W: 1 
#=> E: 1 
#=> H: 1
```

**How it works**

For calculating the frequency I used a Hash populated by: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object

Printing out `freq` from `calculate_frequencies` you can see it:

```
#=> {"H"=>1, "E"=>1, "L"=>3, "O"=>2, "W"=>1, "R"=>1, "D"=>1}
```

---

Alternatively, if you want also not used letters, you can initialise the `freq` hash with all values to 0, then update the hash, something like this:

```
freq = ("A".."Z").each_with_object({}) { |letter, freq| freq[letter] = 0 }
"Hello World!".upcase.gsub!(/\W+/, '').each_char { |letter| freq[letter] += 1 }

#=> {"A"=>0, "B"=>0, "C"=>0, "D"=>1, "E"=>1, "F"=>0, "G"=>0, "H"=>1, "I"=>0, "J"=>0, "K"=>0, "L"=>3, "M"=>0, "N"=>0, "O"=>2, "P"=>0, "Q"=>0, "R"=>1, "S"=>0, "T"=>0, "U"=>0, "V"=>0, "W"=>1, "X"=>0, "Y"=>0, "Z"=>0}
```

---

Finally, to print out the istogram:

```
freq.each { |letter, freq| puts "#{letter}: " + "◼︎" * freq if freq > 0 }

#=> D: ◼︎
#=> E: ◼︎
#=> H: ◼︎
#=> L: ◼︎◼︎◼︎
#=> O: ◼︎◼︎
#=> R: ◼︎
#=> W: ◼︎
```